# node.js toString encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, tostring

I have file encoded with koi8-u

I need to just copy this file, but, through toString()

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('fileOne',function(e,data){
    data = data.toString() // now encoding is damaged

    ???  // my code must be here

    fs.writeFile('fileTwo',data)
})
```

I tried iconv it back using different charsets but with no success. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you write in the same encoding as you read.

Comment: @TheHippo , if I add 'utf8' or 'ascii' encoding to both, read and write, I get the same and there is no encoding for koi8 there ;(

Comment: have you tried `binary`? Why do you need a string? Couldn't this be done with `Buffer` or `streams`?

Comment: @TheHippo Thanks! I tried binary for writeFile and toString and it solved my problem, so you can post it as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to write and read everything with `binary` encoding:

There should be two ways to do this:

**Read data as `Buffer`:**

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('fileOne', function(e, data){
    // data is a buffer
    buffer = data.toString('binary')


    fs.writeFile('fileTwo', {
        'encoding': 'binary'
    }, buffer);
});
```

**Read data as binary encoded `string`:**

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('fileOne', {
        'encoding': 'binary'
    }, function(e, data){
        // data is a string

        fs.writeFile('fileTwo', {
            'encoding': 'binary'
        }, data);
});
```